# upgrade typescript playground on ace to 1.0 RTM

Tags: typescript, tsc

I've been bumbling around attempting to upgrade **[a fork](https://github.com/jdanyow/TypeScriptEditor)** of Basarat Ali Syed's excellent typescript editor project to Typescript 1.0 RTM.

Out of the box the project works without issue however it's using a year old version of typescript and the compiler api has changed quite a bit since then.

To update the project I dropped in the new typescript bits (lib.d.ts and typescriptServices.js) and set about fixing things that were broken due to api changes.

I'm at a point where things compile and the compile errors are surfacing on the ace editor but I can't figure out why globals such as document, alert, window, setTimeout, etc are no longer recognized:

[image: typescript compilation issue]

There must be something simple I'm missing, it's so close to working.  Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

took a look at the code here:  https://typescript.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/compiler/tsc.ts

when compiling it's adding the lib.d.ts to the compiler's list of files, just like any other file:

resolve() :

```
        if (includeDefaultLibrary) {
            var libraryResolvedFile: IResolvedFile = {
                path: this.getDefaultLibraryFilePath(),
                referencedFiles: [],
                importedFiles: []
            };

            // Prepend the library to the resolved list
            resolvedFiles = [libraryResolvedFile].concat(resolvedFiles);
        }
```

compile()  :

```
        this.resolvedFiles.forEach(resolvedFile => {
            var sourceFile = this.getSourceFile(resolvedFile.path);
            compiler.addFile(resolvedFile.path, sourceFile.scriptSnapshot, sourceFile.byteOrderMark, /*version:*/ 0, /*isOpen:*/ false, resolvedFile.referencedFiles);
        });
```

once I started doing the same the compilation errors went away.  must be this step wasn't necessary in older versions of the compiler?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jeremy, been a long time since I looked at it

knowledge of these is supposed to come from `lib.d.ts` Make sure you load it here : https://github.com/basarat/TypeScriptEditor/blob/f8071ebaa2c1f84646fbd1907c28f3c58a643c42/scripts/lib/ace/mode/typescript/lightHarness.js#L83 and here : https://github.com/basarat/TypeScriptEditor/blob/f8071ebaa2c1f84646fbd1907c28f3c58a643c42/scripts/main.js#L33-L35

Comment: I made sure those lines were still executing- didn't solve my problem.

Comment: For future people I am updating it to latest right now https://github.com/basarat/TypeScriptEditor/pull/2 :)